# If $f''(x) +f(x) \geq 0$, show that $f(x) + f(x+\pi) \geq 0$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following exercise and simply have no idea how to solve it whatsoever.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $\mathcal{C}^2$, such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ one has:
$$f''(x)+f(x)\geq0$$
Show that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ one has:
$$f(x)+f(x+\pi)\geq0$$
How can I even begin to tackle a question like this? I'm used to differential equations and solve them without a problem most of the time, but I can't find any information on differential **inequalities**, which is why I'm desperately resorting to this forum (which I know normally doesn't receive problems without much of an attempt behind them very well). What's the general approach one must adopt in order to tackle a problem like this?

Comment: I understand that you couldn’t try solving this problem but do you have any context? It was this out of curiosity?

Comment: OP doesn't specify but this seems like a (good) exercise from an undergraduate ODEs course.

Comment: @whpowell96 I am taking a course currently, with the semester coming to a close, and we haven’t covered these. But after reading your answer I realized that it isn’t hard and requires a bit of re-engineering.

Comment: I looked for a duplicate before posting my answer but I must have missed this. That aside, I think my answer provides something a bit more tractable for the average student given that it doesn't use Green's functions

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming this is given as an exercise in an ODEs course, so the general strategy should be to rewrite it as an ODE, and apply tools from your class.

We begin by rewriting the differential inequality as an inhomogeneous second-order ODE:
$$f''(x) + f(x) = g(x),$$
where $g(x)\geq 0$. Note that the homogeneous equation has solutions $f_1(x) = \sin x$ and $f_2(x) = \cos x$. We can use the [Varation of Parameters Formula](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) to write the solution to the inhomogeneous equation as
$$f_p(x) = -f_1(x)\int_a^x \frac{f_2(y) g(y)}{W[f_1,f_2](y)}~\mathrm{d}y +f_2(x)\int_b^x \frac{f_1(y) g(y)}{W[f_1,f_2](y)}~\mathrm{d}y,$$ where $W[f_1,f_2](y) = f_1(y) f_2'(y) - f_2(y) f_1'(y)$ is the Wronskian of $f_1$ and $f_2$. For these homogeneous solutions, the Wronskian reduces to $-1$. We then have the inhomogeneous solution
$$f_p(x) = \sin x \int_a^x g(y)\cos y~\mathrm{d}y - \cos(x) \int_b^x g(y)\sin y~\mathrm{d}y.$$
Notice that I have written the antiderivative as a definite integral to make the $x$-dependence explicit, as we have to compare this solution at different values of $x$. If we recall that $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin x$ and $\cos(x+\pi) = -\cos x$, we then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_p(x+\pi) &= -\sin x \int_a^{x+\pi} g(y)\cos y~\mathrm{d}y + \cos(x) \int_b^{x+\pi} g(y)\sin y~\mathrm{d}y\\
\implies f_p(x) + f_p(x+\pi) &= -\sin x \int_x^{x+\pi} g(y)\cos y~\mathrm{d}y + \cos(x) \int_x^{x+\pi} g(y)\sin y~\mathrm{d}y
\end{aligned}$$
since the parts of the integrals from $a$ and $b$ to $x$ cancel from the opposite signs. We then combine the integrals and recall the identity $\sin(y-x) = \sin y\cos x - \sin x\cos y$ to obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_p(x) + f_p(x+\pi) &= \int_x^{x+\pi} g(y)(-\sin x \cos y + \cos x\sin y)~\mathrm{d}y = \int_x^{x+\pi} g(y)\sin(y-x)~\mathrm{d}y.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now make the substitution $z = y-x$ to obtain
$$f_p(x) + f_p(x+\pi) = \int_0^\pi g(z+x)\sin z~\mathrm{d}z.$$ $\sin(z) \geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$ and $g$ is nonnegative everwyhere by construction, so the integrand is nonnegative and we have $f_p(x) + f_p(x+\pi) \geq 0~\forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}$, as desired. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: If only I thought of that before seeing your answer.